# Setup nginx limit request burst number at ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am wondering if it is possible to specify the burst value inside the ingress config or ingress controller configmap.

```
limit_req zone=one burst=5 nodelay
```

Br,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

If the aim is to [limit the request processing rate](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/issues/1677) for requests from a particular IP then I think what you can do is use the near-equivalent [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps`](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/74d57c950282484885a74c92d3413110e3b95c69/controllers/nginx/configuration.md#rate-limiting).  It seems to have [a limitation on controlling the burst](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/861#issuecomment-315720951) (which is [five times the limit](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/cdbb9bdd76e1d7f61bca6dac6ff6624b6834ed9e/internal/ingress/annotations/ratelimit/main.go#L34)) but should do the job. There's an example of using this in https://carlos.mendible.com/2018/03/20/secure-your-kubernetes-services-with-nginx-ingress-controller-tls-and-more/

I'm not sure if it gives quite as much flexibility as [the form of `limit_req zone=one burst=5 nodelay`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) but presumably it would work for your purposes?